# Python nested try/except - raise first exception?

Tags: python, try-catch

I'm trying to do a nested try/catch block in Python to print some extra debugging information:

```
try:
    assert( False )
except:
    print "some debugging information"
    try:
        another_function()
    except:
        print "that didn't work either"
    else:
        print "ooh, that worked!"
    raise
```

I'd like to always re-raise the first error, but this code appears to raise the second error (the one caught with "that didn't work either"). Is there a way to re-raise the first exception?

Comment: what are you trying to do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`raise`, with no arguments, raises the last exception.  To get the behavior you want, put the error in a variable so that you can raise with that exception instead:

```
try:
    assert( False )
# Right here
except Exception as e:
    print "some debugging information"
    try:
        another_function()
    except:
        print "that didn't work either"
    else:
        print "ooh, that worked!"
    raise e
```

Note however that you should capture for a more specific exception rather than just `Exception`.

Answer (score 2):

You should capture the first Exception in a variable.

```
try:
    assert(False)
except Exception as e:
    print "some debugging information"
    try:
        another_function()
    except:
        print "that didn't work either"
    else:
        print "ooh, that worked!"
    raise e
```

`raise` by default will raise the last Exception.

Answer (score 0):

`raise` raises the last exception caught unless you specify otherwise.  If you want to reraise an early exception, you have to bind it to a name for later reference.

In Python 2.x:

```
try:
    assert False
except Exception, e:
    ...
    raise e
```

In Python 3.x:

```
try:
    assert False
except Exception as e:
    ...
    raise e
```

Unless you are writing general purpose code, you want to catch only the exceptions you are prepared to deal with... so in the above example you would write:

```
except AssertionError ... :
```