# multiple exception handler in python

Tags: python, exception

I'm writing code that has to deal with a lot of `IndexError` exceptions.
So, I used a `try except` block:

```
try:
    <do some level_1 calculations>
except IndexError:
    <change to level_2 calculations>
```

But, what if my exception-handler again raises another `IndexError`?
How can I safely put another `IndexError` exception with this code structure so that, if the level_2 calculation again gets caught in an `IndexError`, then the code runs "level_3 calculations" as an exception again and so on.

Comment: nested try and except

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19107796/python-nested-try-except-raise-first-exception

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just nest `try except` blocks, like so:

```
try:
    <do some level_1 calculations>
except IndexError:
    try:
        <change to level_2 calculations>
    except IndexError:
        try:
            <change to level_3 calculations>
        except IndexError:
            <change to level_4 calculations>
```

But that would look messy and can cause trouble if you mess up formatting, it would probably be better to use a list of functions that you loop over attempting different calculations until all have failed and then you handle the exception some other way.

```
calulators = [
                 level_1_calculation_function,
                 level_2_calculation_function,
                 level_3_calculation_function,
             ]

for attempt in range(len(calculators)):
    try:
        result = calculators[attempt]
        break #If we've reached here, the calculation was successful
    except IndexError:
        attempt += 1
else:
    #If none of the functions worked and broke out of the loop, we execute this.
    <handle_exception>
```

Comment: Glad it helped. Please remember to upvote useful answers and, when you can, select the one that worked best for you as your accepted answer.

Comment: you could just use range instead of a while and also stick the calculations in a dict

Comment: @PadraicCunningham That is a much better solution. I re-edited to use a list of functions and a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Put the calculations/funcs in a list:

```
from random import choice
from operator import mul, add

funcs = [mul, add]

for f in funcs:
    try:
        i = l[choice([1, 2, 3])]
        calc = f(i[0], i[1])
        print(calc)
        break # break if you want the first successful calc to be the last
    except IndexError as e:
        print(e)
        continue
```

If you run the code you will see random indexError's being caught.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, when you are writing code you should be aware of what can happen at any stage and you should place your exception handlers accordingly.

Saying that, if you are performing a series of operations where there are multiple places that can cause a specific exception, you can enclose the whole block into a single exception handler of an appropriate type. In other cases, when you require a different behavior as a result of some other exceptions, define separate handlers.

Both ways are correct logically and rather a question of design.

Answer (score 0):

Nesting the try-except block is the right way to go. Because possible exceptions occurs **outside** of your try block.

There is one another way, but that is not something that *I will advice you if you do not have very specific reasons to use it*. It makes things look a bit more messy and requires you to use default try-except blocks nested within each other with a final try-except block to cover them all!

```
class FirstLevelFuncException(Exception):
    pass

class SecondLevelFuncException(Exception):
    pass

class ThirdLevelFuncException(Exception):
    pass

try: 
# This is the base try block that will cover your code and catch Function Level based exceptions
    try:
        <do some level_1 calculations>
    except IndexError:
        try:
            <change to level_2 calculations>
        except IndexError:
            try:
                <change to level_3 calculations>
            except IndexError:
                <change to level_4 calculations>
            else:
                raise SecondLevelFuncException()
        else:
            raise FirstLevelFuncException()
    else:
        pass
except Exception as e:
    print e
```

That will try to execute functions in given order and when it completes a step without error, it will raise exception related to previous level, so you can keep track of the execution.

But as I said, **that is not a good and proper way to go** unless you have very specific needs.